# How to subset lists in R using something similar to matrix indexation?

Tags: r, list, indexing

When I want all the rows and a particular column of a matrix or a data frame we use `df[ ,"column x"]`. Is there something as fast to extract the i-th element of each data frame inside a list?

For example, get the 2nd row of each matrix in the following list

```
example <- list(matrix(1:9,3,3) , matrix(11:19,3,3), matrix(21:29,3,3))
```

I wonder if something like `example[[:]][2,]` exists.
Please do not propose solutions with loops or s(l)apply.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot do this without any kind of `*apply` (the proposed `Map` is an alias of `mapply`). For your particular example, you can `rbind` all the matrices together and than take the second row of each of them through:

```
do.call(rbind,example)[seq(2,by=3,length.out=length(example)),]
```

Of course the above works only when the matrices of your list can be `rbind`ed together.

Comment: If you are going to change the list to a 2D matrix, you can also create a 3D matrix and then subset with: `do.call(abind:::abind, c(example, along=3))[2,,]`

Comment: To bad that there is no analog of matrix indexation in lists. It feel like a natural extension.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
lapply(example, function(x) x[2,])
```

I know you specifically requested that no one give you the right answer, but I couldn't help it. This is how you do it in R.

Maybe i found a loophole, you didn't say I couldn't use `Map()`

```
Map(function(x) x[2,], example)
```